# Using Scrapy and Splash to Follow javascript pagination

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am using Scrapy and splash to extract the data. I am looking to find a way to follow pagination that was powered with javascript. The URL is not changing it is always the same no matter on what page you are.

```
<li class="btn-next"><a href="javascript:ctrl.set_pageReload(2)">Next</a></li>
```

I have tried with lua script and splash to click on the element but this does not work:

```
    """function main(splash)
local url = splash.args.url
assert(splash:go(url))
assert(splash:wait(1))
assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("btn-next")[0].click()'))
assert(splash:wait(0.75))
-- return result as a JSON object
return {html = splash:html()}                
end """



def parse(self, response):
    section = response.css('li.li-result')
    for item in section:
        yield{
            'manufacturer' :  item.css('span.brand::text').extract_first(),
            'model' : item.css('span.sub-title::text').extract_first(),
            'engine_size' :  item.css('span.nowrap::text').extract_first(),
            'model_type' : item.css('span span.nowrap::text').extract_first(),
            'old_price' : item.css('li.li-result p.old-prix span::text').extract_first(),    
            'price' : item.css('li.li-result p.prix::text').extract_first(),
            'consumption' : item.css('li.li-result div.desc::text').extract_first(),
            'date' : item.css('p.btn-publication::text').extract_first(),
            'fuel_type' : item.css('div.bc-info div.upper::text').extract_first(),
            'mileage' : item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[1].extract(),
            'year' : item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[2].extract(),
            'transmission_type' : item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[3].extract(),
            'add_number' : item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[4].extract(),

        }

    next_page = response.css('li.btn-next').extract_first() #pagination    
    if next_page != 0:
        print(response)
        yield(SplashRequest(next_page, self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            cache_args=['lua_source'],
            args={'lua_source': script},  

        ))
```

Is it even possible to do it in this way? Appreciate help.

Comment: can you please tell us what site? you may not need to render JS.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Turns out to be the same site I had a question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900038/how-to-click-on-javascriptctrl-set-pagereload)

Answer (score 1):

First, two issues with the Lua script:

1. `.btn-next` is a non-interactive `li` element, so clicking on it does nothing.
   Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event
2. The pagination is slow, so waiting for 0.75 seconds is too short.

To fix that:

1. Click on its `a` child element (see alternative below).
2. Wait for 1.5 seconds or more.

```lua
function main(splash)
  local url = splash.args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  -- assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("btn-next")[0].click()'))          -- Change this
  assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("btn-next")[0].children[0].click()')) -- to this
  -- assert(splash:wait(0.75)) -- Change this
  assert(splash:wait(1.5))     -- to this
  -- return result as a JSON object
  return {html = splash:html()}                
end
```

(The above shows JavaScript navigation to page 2 works in [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html), but we need more work to scrape subsequent pages with Scrapy-Splash.)

Next, two issues with the `parse` method:

1. `next_page` is the HTML string of the `li` element, so it cannot be passed as the `url` argument to `SplashRequest`.
2. `next_page` may be `None`, but never `0`.

To fix that, see the solution.

## Solution

1. Pass `response.url` and `response.text`, and then call [`splash:set_content()`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-set-content) to restore the state in the next request.

   - Pass `dontfilter=True` to skip the duplicate check for `url`.
   - Wait for 2 seconds, though it's sometimes still too short (see alternative below).
2. Check that `next_page` is not `None` instead.

```py
script = """function main(splash)
  local url = splash.args.url
  local content = splash.args.content
  assert(splash:set_content(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url))
  assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("btn-next")[0].children[0].click()'))
  assert(splash:wait(2))
  return {html = splash:html()}
end"""
```

```py
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    section = response.css('li.li-result')
    for item in section:
        yield {
            'manufacturer': item.css('span.brand::text').extract_first(),
            'model': item.css('span.sub-title::text').extract_first(),
            'engine_size': item.css('span.nowrap::text').extract_first(),
            'model_type': item.css('span span.nowrap::text').extract_first(),
            'old_price': item.css('li.li-result p.old-prix span::text').extract_first(),
            'price': item.css('li.li-result p.prix::text').extract_first(),
            'consumption': item.css('li.li-result div.desc::text').extract_first(),
            'date': item.css('p.btn-publication::text').extract_first(),
            'fuel_type': item.css('div.bc-info div.upper::text').extract_first(),
            'mileage': item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[1].extract(),
            'year': item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[2].extract(),
            'transmission_type': item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[3].extract(),
            'add_number': item.css('li.li-result div.bc-info ul div::text')[4].extract(),
        }

    next_page = response.css('li.btn-next').extract_first()
    # print(next_page)
    if next_page is not None:
        yield SplashRequest(
            response.url,
            self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            args={
                'lua_source': script,
                'content': response.text,
            },
            cache_args=['lua_source'],
            dont_filter=True,
        )
```

(Comment out `for item in section:` block and uncomment `print(next_page)` to easily verify the solution.)

---

## Some alternatives

An alternative to clicking the button is to call the function directly:

```lua
-- assert(splash:runjs('document.getElementsByClassName("btn-next")[0].children[0].click()'))
assert(splash:runjs('ctrl.set_pageReload(ctrl.context.cur_page + 1)'))
```

An alternative to hardcoding a possibly insufficient wait time is to periodically check for a set variable and then wait for the jQuery ready callback (optionally hardcode an initial wait time):

```lua
assert(splash:runjs('window.notReloaded = 1'))
-- assert(splash:wait(2)) -- Optional initial wait time
local exit = false
while (exit == false)
do
  result, error = splash:wait_for_resume([[
    function main(splash) {
      window.notReloaded ? splash.error() : splash.resume();
    }
  ]])
  if result then
    exit = true
  else
    splash:wait(0.2) -- Adjust resolution as desired
  end
end
assert(splash:wait_for_resume([[
  function main(splash) {
    $(() => splash.resume());
  }
]]))
```

Comment: Here's the fix: https://github.com/acjh/Scrapy-Splash_javascript-integration/commit/95eb8636f141626ec015fca40f64dd0618bd0a74. Mainly, you were not passing your project settings (most importantly `SplashMiddleware` in `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES`) to `CrawlerProcess`, so the Lua script wasn't even run. Now you can reduce `splash:wait(10)` to 2 and see that it still works.